# Android web service login 'unfortunately has stopped working'?

Tags: android, web-services

Hi I have been trying to get a web service login to work for some time. At the moment after I enter username and password and press login the app screen just closes and 'unfortunately RemoteLogin has stopped working.' I have tried looking through the log cat but can't make sense of it myself, I have never worked in Android with web services before and struggling. Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.remotelogin;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private EditText txtName, txtPassword;
    private Button login;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_Pwd);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);



    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                     String userName = txtName.getText().toString();
                     String userPwd = txtPassword.getText().toString();

                    if (userName.trim().equals(""))
                        txtName.setError("Please enter username");
                    if (userPwd.trim().equals(""))
                        txtPassword.setError("Please enter password");
                    if (!userName.trim().equals("") && !userPwd.trim().equals(""))
                    {

                        new GetAuthentication(MainActivity.this).execute("RemoteLogin",userName, userPwd);
                    }



                }
            });
        }



     private class GetAuthentication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
            {

            private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            //Webservice URL - WSDL File location    
            private static final String URL = "http://84.51.246.251/ttms/remoteaccess.asmx?WSDL";
            ProgressDialog pd ;
            private Context _context;

           public GetAuthentication(Context context) {
                _context = context;
            }



            protected void onPreExecute ()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd = new ProgressDialog(_context);
                pd.setTitle("Processing");
                pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                pd.show();
            }




         @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (params[0].trim().equals(""))
            return "";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, params[0]);  

            request.addProperty("userName", params[1]);
            request.addProperty("password", params[2]);

          // params[0] --> function name that you have passed from activity
          // params[1] --> username name that you have passed from activity
          // params[2] --> password that you have passed from activity


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try
            {
                httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + params[0], envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                return response.toString();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (pd.isShowing())
                    pd.dismiss();
                return "Error";
            }

        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String str)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(str);
            try
            {
                if (pd.isShowing())
                    pd.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception e){}

            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Error"))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again after some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
            {

               // here parse your json or whatever you are retrieving from the server
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

activity_main xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_Pwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:hint="Password"
         android:padding="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.remotelogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
07-23 10:22:20.347: D/libEGL(8567): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
07-23 10:22:20.347: D/libEGL(8567): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
07-23 10:22:20.397: D/OpenGLRenderer(8567): Enabling debug mode 0
07-23 10:22:56.842: E/dalvikvm(8567): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity$GetAuthentication.doInBackground
07-23 10:22:56.842: W/dalvikvm(8567): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1123 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/example/remotelogin/MainActivity$GetAuthentication;
07-23 10:22:56.842: D/dalvikvm(8567): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0013
07-23 10:22:56.842: D/dalvikvm(8567): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2209 at 0x19 in Lcom/example/remotelogin/MainActivity$GetAuthentication;.doInBackground
07-23 10:22:56.842: D/dalvikvm(8567): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x220c at 0x2f in Lcom/example/remotelogin/MainActivity$GetAuthentication;.doInBackground
07-23 10:22:56.842: I/dalvikvm(8567): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x0ddd at 0x32 in Lcom/example/remotelogin/MainActivity$GetAuthentication;.doInBackground
07-23 10:22:56.842: D/dalvikvm(8567): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x220f at 0x3b in Lcom/example/remotelogin/MainActivity$GetAuthentication;.doInBackground
07-23 10:22:56.882: W/dalvikvm(8567): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bc0318)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity$GetAuthentication.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:108)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity$GetAuthentication.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-23 10:22:56.892: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     ... 5 more
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567): Activity com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4141c938 that was originally added here
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4141c938 that was originally added here
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity$GetAuthentication.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:95)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at com.example.remotelogin.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-23 10:22:57.263: E/WindowManager(8567):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your soap jar in libs as well as in build path.